# Late Answer review queue explosion?

Tags: discussion, late-answers

So all of a sudden today the Late Answer review queue exploded to more than 500 posts. All that I looked at were not new, but something kicked them back in to play.

As a still newish person here, what happened?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/

Comment: So, these are old answers to old questions that have suddenly come back as new answers to old questions.  What would be the proper way to process them?

Comment: Some are even accepted answers. But the meta SE link from @Loong is the answer - the rep limit to be tossed in the queue was increased, so a batch of answers are now retroactively thrown into the queue. Generally, we should probably let sleeping answers lie?

Comment: @JonCuster well, I'd say don't give old answers a free pass just for being old. If you're reviewing, judge the answers as normal. But in general, if an answer has sat around for a long time already, it's probably fine unless you see some reason for it not to be.

Comment: That happened to me too.  I came here to ask the same question.

Comment: Given that the one-time surplus is large but not unmanageable, this is a good opportunity for 500+ rep members to have a go at the review queues and get some badges.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty sigh... Only 20 allowed...

Comment: I just went to look - and the "late answer" queue is empty. Well done to our reviewers - or did something or somebody reverse this?

Comment: I think everyone went and nibbled away at it. It did go faster than I thought it would...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Late Answers Review Queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers) contains answers which were posted by new users much later than when the question was asked. Late answers tend to be seen by fewer people than answers posted soon after the question was asked, so the review queue helps ensure that these answers meet the same quality standards as all other answers.<sup>[[source]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)</sup>

Following this [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/271002), **the decision threshold for late answers to enter the Late Answers Review Queue has been raised from 10 to 50 reputation.** This applies to all sites, not just physics.SE.

Due to this change, many old answers retroactively entered the Late Answers Review Queue. This caused a spike in the number of answers in the queue.